# Cannot get type of generic object in a list

Tags: scala, generics, types, shapeless

I have the following trait:

```
trait Storage[C <: Config] {
  def get(name: String, version: Int): Option[C]
  def list: List[(String, String)]
  def register(config: C): Boolean
}
```

and I want to create the following class:

```
class MultiStorage[C <: Config](storages: List[Storage[_ <: C]]) extends Storage[C] {
    def get(name: String, version: Int): Option[C] = {...}
    def list: List[(String, String)] = {...}    
    def register(config: C) = {...}
```

If not clear, the meaning is that a `MultiStorage` stores elements of type `C` (or subtype) in several storages, each of them containing elements of a single type.

I am fighting with generics to implement the register method. The idea is that depending on the type of object I want to register, I need to choose the right storage to register on, something like:

```
def register(config: C) = {
   storages.foreach(s => {
      if (typeOf(s) is Storage[C]) { // same type of config
           s.register(config)
           return
      }
   }) 
}
```

I made several attempts with generics and type tags, however nothing useful to share here. I am probably thinking I need to add another type tag to distinguish what I receive in register and what is declared as type of the storage.

One of the ideas I tried was having a method in `Storage` that returns the type:

```
protected def getType()(implicit tag: TypeTag[C]): universe.Type = typeOf[C]
```

but on the caller side I was able to get as result something like `_$1`, which I honestly don't understand what it means.

Another try was to use `shapeless`, but in this case I am not sure if it is possible having a multi-storage containing an arbitrary number of elements in an `HList` storage

Comment: Suppose we have `trait Config`
  `object config1 extends Config`
  `object config2 extends Config`
`object storage1 extends Storage[config1.type]`
`object storage2 extends Storage[config2.type]`
`val multiStorage = new MultiStorage[Config](List(storage1, storage2))`
Then what are `multiStorage.register(config1)`, `multiStorage.register(config2)`? None of `s` is of type `Storage[C]` i.e. `Storage[Config]`.

Comment: As I said, I probably misused the generics. In the example you mentioned, I would like that  `multiStorage.register(config1)` internally calls `storage1.register(config1)` and `multiStorage.register(config2)` internally calls `storage2.register(config2)`

Answer (score 2):

The runtime class needs to be made available, for example:

```
class Config
class FooConfig extends Config
class BarConfig extends Config

trait Storage[C <: Config] {
    val ctag: ClassTag[C]

    def get(name: String, version: Int): Option[C]
    def list: List[(String, String)]
    def register(config: C): Boolean
}

class FooStorage(implicit val ctag: ClassTag[FooConfig]) extends Storage[FooConfig] {
    override def get(name: String, version: Int): Option[FooConfig] = ???

    override def list: List[(String, String)] = ???

    override def register(config: FooConfig): Boolean = ???
}

class BarStorage(implicit val ctag: ClassTag[BarConfig]) extends Storage[BarConfig] {
    override def get(name: String, version: Int): Option[BarConfig] = ???

    override def list: List[(String, String)] = ???

    override def register(config: BarConfig): Boolean = ???
}


class MultiStorage[C <: Config](storages: List[Storage[_ <: C]])(implicit val ctag: ClassTag[C]) extends Storage[C] {
    def get(name: String, version: Int): Option[C] = ???

    def list: List[(String, String)] = ???

    def register(config: C): Boolean = {
        storages.foreach(storage => {
            if (storage.ctag.runtimeClass.isAssignableFrom(config.getClass)) {

            }
        })
        ???
    }
}
```

As traits can't have constructor parameters, the implicit class tag needs to be repeated in every class implementing the trait. If your class structure allows `Storage` to be an abstract class instead, the amount of boilerplate can be reduced:

```
abstract class Storage[C <: Config](implicit val ctag: ClassTag[C]) {

    def get(name: String, version: Int): Option[C]
    def list: List[(String, String)]
    def register(config: C): Boolean
}

class FooStorage extends Storage[FooConfig] {
    override def get(name: String, version: Int): Option[FooConfig] = ???

    override def list: List[(String, String)] = ???

    override def register(config: FooConfig): Boolean = ???
}
```

Comment: it looks like what I want, thanks! However when I create `FooStorage` it complains that `ctag` value cannot be find (I create it in another file). I am try to follow the second approach, since my trait can become an abstract class

Answer (score 0):

Possible approach with Shapeless is

```
import shapeless.{::, HList, HNil}

object App {
  trait Config
  object config1 extends Config
  object config2 extends Config

  trait Storage[C <: Config] {
    def get(name: String, version: Int): Option[C]
    def list: List[(String, String)]
    def register(config: C): Boolean
  }

  object storage1 extends Storage[config1.type] {
    override def get(name: String, version: Int): Option[config1.type] = ???
    override def list: List[(String, String)] = ???
    override def register(config: config1.type): Boolean = {
      println("storage1#register")
      true
    }
  }
  object storage2 extends Storage[config2.type] {
    override def get(name: String, version: Int): Option[config2.type] = ???
    override def list: List[(String, String)] = ???
    override def register(config: config2.type): Boolean = {
      println("storage2#register")
      true
    }
  }

  class MultiStorage[L <: HList](storages: L) /*extends Storage[C]*/ {
//    def get(name: String, version: Int): Option[C] = ???
    def list: List[(String, String)] = ???
    def register[C <: Config](config: C)(implicit find: Find[C, L]): Boolean = find(config, storages).register(config)
  }

  trait Find[C <: Config, L <: HList] {
    def apply(config: C, l: L): Storage[C]
  }

  trait LowPriorityFind {
    implicit def tail[C <: Config, L <: HList, C1 <: Config, T <: HList](implicit
      ev: L <:< (Storage[C1] :: T),
      find: Find[C, T]): Find[C, L] = (config, l) => find(config, l.tail)
  }

  object Find extends LowPriorityFind {
    implicit def head[C <: Config, L <: HList, T <: HList](implicit 
      ev: L <:< (Storage[C] :: T)): Find[C, L] = (_, l) => l.head
  }

  val multiStorage = new MultiStorage(storage1 :: storage2 :: HNil)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    multiStorage.register(config1) // storage1#register
    multiStorage.register(config2) // storage2#register
  }
}
```

Making `MultiStorage` extend `Storage` can be too restrictive. We could write

```
class MultiStorage(storages: List[Storage[_ <: Config]] /*i.e. List[Storage[T] forSome { type T <: Config}]*/) 
  extends Storage[T forSome { type T <: Config }] /*i.e. just Storage[Config]*/
```

i.e. `Storage` of some unknown type `T <: Config`. But since we can register configs of any type `T <: Config` it should be more like `Storage[T forAll { type T <: Config }]` or `Storage[[T <: Config]T]` if such syntax existed in Scala but actually Scala doesn't have [rank-2 types](https://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2010/07/02/higher-rank-polymorphism-in-scala/).