# Design a trait which contains object of its type internally and choose at runtime what to use

Tags: java, scala, design-patterns, type-erasure

In Scala, I am trying to design the following thing.

I have a hierarchy of `Config` objects. I have around 10 different subclasses of `Config` right now and this number will grow.

I want to create an interface `Storage` with two methods: `add(c: Config): Unit` and `get(name: String): Config` to be able to add/retrieve `Config` objects to an underlying storage (db, file, in-memory set, etc.).

Every `ConfigImpl` object needs to be stored in its own way: e.g. `ConfigImplA` objects will be stored in `StorageImplA`, `ConfigImplB` in `StorageImplB`, etc.

Basically every `ConfigImpl` sub-type has its own `StorageImpl` which is independent from the others.

Finally, I want to create a top-level component `MultiStorage extends Storage` class which contains internally a `List[_ <: Storage]` (with every Storage containing a single type of objects).
The `get` of `MultiStorage` will try to fetch the `Config` from every Storage in the list in order, while the `add` will register a new `c: Config` in the storage 'storing' object of the same (sub)-type of `c`:

```
List[_ <: Storage] storages = List(storageA, storageB, storageC, ...) \\ this is externally configured 

def add(c: Config) = storages.find(s => typeOf[s] == typeOf[c]).get.add(c)
```

As I explained here ([Cannot get type of generic object in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55079296/cannot-get-type-of-generic-object-in-a-list)) I am having troubles with type management in this kind of situation. I would like to understand if the overall design of this thing is not ideal and I should approach it differently or if there is a way to properly play with types to implement a clean solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

By using `List[_ <: Storage]` you are asking to erase the (static) type information. When you get elements from it, their type is just `Storage`. (Also there's pretty much no difference between
 `List[_ <: Storage]` and  `List[Storage]`, because `List` is covariant.)

But it looks like for your requirements, runtime class information is enough:

```
trait Storage {
  def configClass: Class[_ <: Config]
  // other methods
}

def add(c: Config) = storages.find(s => s.configClass.isInstance(c)).get.add(c)
```

On the other hand, it looks like your `Storage` should itself be generic if it can't store *any* `Config` but only specific subtypes:

```
trait Storage[T <: Config] {
  def configClass: Class[T]
  def add(c: T): Unit
  def get(name: String): T
}

val storages: List[Storage[_ <: Config]] = ...
```

which actually complicates `add` a little (but `asInstanceOf` doesn't really make it less safe):

```
def add(c: Config) = storages.find(s => s.configClass.isInstance(c)).get.asInstanceOf[Storage[Config]].add(c)
```

Note: after answering I looked at the linked question, and this is pretty close to ollik1's answer there.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to handle this is to make `Storage` itself be aware of type(s) of config it can store, and make `.add` return a boolean:

```
class SomeStorage extends Storage {
   def add(c: Config): Boolean = c match {
     case config: MyConfig => storeMyConfig(config); true
     case _ => false
   }
}

class MultiStorage(storages: Storage*) extends Storage {
  def add(c: Config): Boolean = storages.find(_.add(c)).isDefined
}
```

This is a bit more flexible than parametrizing like the other answer suggests, because you could have the same `Storage` implementation handle multiple types of `Config`, and even build `MultiStorage`s hierarchically:

```
val someStorage = MultiStorage(
  MultiStorage(storage1, storage2),
  MultiStorage(storage3, storage4)
)
```